# how to make my blog archive links work in panels?

Tags: views

I am a newbie with drupal 7. Currently I migrate blog from a drupal 7 site without panel and PE  to another drupal 7 site with Panel and PE, but somehow the archive view on the right side of the panel could not direct the archived content to a panel. I mean, when I click on the archive links, it direct to a archived content but not on a panel. How should I put the archive links view and linked archive content in a panel so that all the pages look the same? I want the linked archived content page to be a panel with right side archive view links still there.

Any help and advice is highly appreciated.

Thanks